# Can't get mod_rewrite to work

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get url from:

192.168.0.1/movie-page.php?id=123

to:

192.168.0.1/movie/movie-name

or even (for now):

192.168.0.1/movie/123

I've simplified it by using this url (to get something working):

192.168.0.1/pet_care_info_07_07_2008.php  TO  192.168.0.1/pet-care/

my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pet-care/?$ pet_care_info_07_07_2008.php [NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried many combinations but no luck and my patience is running out...

I am running this on my local NAS which should have mod_rewrite enabled by default. I have tested .htaccess by entering random string in .htaccess file and opening the page, I got 404 error. I assume this means that .htaccess is being used since the page stops functioning if the file is malformed.

Comment: I've followed a tutorial: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ I simply copy pasted the code, and this isn't even the first tutorial that didn't work. I followed several tutorials but can't even get the basics to work, so I don't even know if it's actually working properly...

Comment: Have you really checked that the NAS has apache installed. And is serving content from the correct directory you are trying this on, just putting a random string into your NAS url is not testing.

Comment: apache is definetely installed and enabled and is serving up php pages. Random string was added to .htaccess file which then made all pages return 404, once removed the pages worked ok again. this I thing at least shows that .htaccess is being used.

Comment: It does seem like the issue is on server side, as I cant even get redirect to work, is there a good way to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rewrite:
`192.168.0.1/movie-page.php?id=123` too

`192.168.0.1/movie/movie-name` or `192.168.0.1/movie/123`

Then you would do something like, but will require you manually add a rewrite for any new route (fancy url) you want, and eventually you may want your script to create routes dynamically or have a single entry point to sanitize:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^movie/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ movie-page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So a better method is to route everything through the rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then handle the route by splitting the `$_GET['route']` with `explode()`

```
<?php 
//192.168.0.1/movie/movie-name
$route = (isset($_GET['route'])?explode('/',$_GET['route']):null);

if(!empty($route)){
    //example
    $route[0]; //movie
    $route[1]; //movie-name
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 for using a PHP router script to handle the rewrite logic rather than writing unique htaccess rules per page.

Comment: If I understand correctly I wouldn't need a rule for each page, I would just use regexp to insert id a variable. Also is this method not inefficient performance wise?

Comment: If you wanted to pass eg: `192.168.0.1/blog/123` then you would need a rewite. Its how many MVC frameworks handle the route, it cant be that bad ;p

Comment: one more thing, why doesn't this work: ^movie-page.php?id=2270$ index.php  ? This works though: ^movie-page.php$ index.php  This is just for testing/learning purposes but I dont get why the first line doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^movie/([0-9]*)$ /movie-page.php?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```

That will give the movie ID version with a numeric ID.